# Bootstrap-Table: Not Refreshing Data-URL in IE11 (no server-side call) after table update

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I'm having problems with the **"Bootstrap-Table"** plugin: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table

In IE11 only, the data-url source AJAX method only gets called on the 1st page load, and doesn't get called on any subsequent page refreshes. Something gets cached. Therefore, whenever I redraw the table after an update, it doesn't show the latest correct information -- and this is only in IE11.

**I added the following in document.onReady and it still doesn't work**

```
$('#delegateTable').bootstrapTable('refresh', {url: 'populateDelegates.action'});
```

The usage of this plugin is HTML-based, as below:

```
<table id="delegateTable" 
   data-toggle="table" data-url="populateDelegates.action" 
   data-response-handler="delegatesResponseHandler">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         ....
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

The solution proposed here is
https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/137

```
add data-method="post"
```

And that did fix it. But is that the right approach? I couldn't find any documentation whatsoever about this crazy plugin from the official site and whenever he fixes bugs he doesn't explain what he does and why -- nor are there are any complete descriptions. I was lucky I came across this quick fix! Just not sure if I should really do a POST?

(Note: I downloaded the latest v12.1 and it still has this IE problem.)